# empty value of a key if the array has duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 78
            [post_id] => 3
            [post_user_added_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 76
            [post_id] => 3
            [post_user_added_id] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 78
            [post_id] => 3
            [post_user_added_id] => 12
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 76
            [post_id] => 9
            [post_user_added_id] => 15
        )

     [4] => Array
         (
             [user_id] => 77
             [post_id] => 9
             [post_user_added_id] => 15
         )
```

what i want to do is if the key `post_id` is repeated i just want to empty it and keep one so my final array will look like this

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 78
            [post_id] => 3
            [post_user_added_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 76
            [post_id] => 
            [post_user_added_id] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 78
            [post_id] => 
            [post_user_added_id] => 12
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 76
            [post_id] => 9
            [post_user_added_id] => 15
        )

     [4] => Array
         (
             [user_id] => 77
             [post_id] => 
             [post_user_added_id] => 15
         )
```

i have tried this code but it doesn't seem to work it deletes the whole array

```
                           foreach($arry as $k => $v)
                            {
                                foreach($arry as $key => $value)
                                {
                                    if($k != $key && $v['post_id'] == $value['post_id'])
                                    {
                                        unset($arry [$k]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            print_r($arry);
```

Comment: Unsetting completely deletes an entry (along with its key). What exactly do you want this blank value to be? Null? Empty string?

Comment: empty string  or null any would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform `foreach` with `ternary` operator

```
$last = null;//this will keep the previous post_id
foreach($arr as &$v){
 ($last && $last == $v['post_id']) ? ($v['post_id'] = '') : ($last = $v['post_id']);
}
print_r($arr);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/RiU9J

Comment: What if the post_id is not the same as the last one, but another previous entry?

Comment: @NigelRen this can be a case, but as mentioned in the OP they are in order.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use a stack for comparison?
edit: rewritten the code...

```
$stack=[];
foreach ($array as $index => $subarray){
    if(in_array($subarray['post_id'], $stack)) {
        $array[$index]['post_id'] = null;

    }
    else $stack[]=$subarray['post_id'];
}
print_r($array);
```

example: https://3v4l.org/FsPUG
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

here try this.

```
$tempArr = [];
$resArr = [];
foreach($orignalArr as $key=>$obj){
    if(in_array($obj['post_id'], $tempArr)){
        $obj['post_id'] = '';
        $resArr[] = $obj;
    }else{
        $tempArr[] = $obj['post_id'];
        $resArr[] = $obj;
    }
}

print_r($resArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

use of your array value in instead of $arr and try to filter array like the following code :

```
 $arr = array(
        array(
            'user_id'=>15,
            'post_id'=>3,
            'post_user_added_id'=>2
            ),

            array(
            'user_id'=>16,
            'post_id'=>3,
            'post_user_added_id'=>2
            ),

         array(
            'user_id'=>18,
            'post_id'=>3,
            'post_user_added_id'=>2
            ),

             array(
            'user_id'=>18,
            'post_id'=>3,
            'post_user_added_id'=>2
            ),

             array(
            'user_id'=>16,
            'post_id'=>3,
            'post_user_added_id'=>2
            ),
    );

    $postids = array();
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){

        if(in_array($val['post_id'], $postids)){ 
            $arr[$key]['post_id'] = '';
        }else{
            $postids[] = $val['post_id'];
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);exit;
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 15
            [post_id] => 3
            [post_user_added_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 16
            [post_id] => 
            [post_user_added_id] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 18
            [post_id] => 
            [post_user_added_id] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 18
            [post_id] => 
            [post_user_added_id] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 16
            [post_id] => 
            [post_user_added_id] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
// example code
$arrayResult = array();
$arry = [
    1 =>
        [
            'user_id' => 78,
            'post_id' => 3,
            'post_user_added_id' => 2
        ],

    2=>
        [
            'user_id' => 76,
            'post_id' => 3,
            'post_user_added_id' => 16
        ],
    3 =>
        [
            'user_id' => 78,
        'post_id' => 3,
            'post_user_added_id' => 12
        ],

    4 =>
        [
            'user_id' => 76,
            'post_id' => 9,
            'post_user_added_id' => 15
        ],

     5 =>
         [
            'user_id' => 77,
            'post_id' => 9,
            'post_user_added_id' => 15
         ]];

$final = array();
foreach($arry as $a)
{
    if (in_array($a['post_id'], $arrayResult)) {
        $a['post_id'] = 0;
    }else{
        $arrayResult[] = $a['post_id'];
    }
    $final[] = $a;
}

var_dump($final);
```